# How is it possible to return back the changed timezone after the completion of tests?

Tags: batch-file

I was creating a project in which I needed to change the timezone to UTC so that tests run considering the timezone UTC only. So I have created this batch code:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`tzutil /g`) DO SET PREVIOUS_TZ=%%F
tzutil /s "UTC"
cmd.exe /c npm run test:unit:base
tzutil /s "%PREVIOUS_TZ%"
```

I wonder how is it possible to return the previous timezone from UTC after the completion of tests. I found out that we can use "posttest" to hook the completion of tests. Thus, again how can we return the previous timezone with batch script?

Comment: Where is the problem? Your code looks like a working sample. If it doesn't work, add the content of `PREVIOUS_TZ` and the error message

Comment: @jeb, hi))), no no everything works ok. I just wanted to know if it is possible to somehow return previous timezone after the completion of tests?

Comment: Isn't that what the last command does?

Comment: @SomethingDark, this is what I tried at least but is not working I mean after the completion of tests my timezone remained UTC and I need to manually change it by going into settings. I think of using posttest hook. What do you think?))

Comment: please can you do `echo "%PREVIOUS_TZ%"` and show the exact result, including quotes.

Comment: @Mil - I don't know what a "posttest hook" is and I don't mess with timezones. Show us what `echo %PREVIOUS_TZ%` returns and we'll tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, I get "UTC"

Comment: So then it means that you had UTC to start off with. It has to be something else in order to change it.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, I had "UTC+3" but after the test, I lose UTC+3 and get UTC. Is it possible to use posttest:"run another batch script". What do you think?))

Comment: ok, but there is no such timezone as `UTC+3` in the `tzutil` command. So your second run simply inherited the newly created UTC time zone you created. It would give you an error if you added `tzutil /s "UTC+3"` I suggest you run `tzutil /?` to get a better understand of the command and `tzutil /l` to list valid time zones.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, my apologies Gerhard, yeah all works just a bit confusion happened))). The problem happens when tests fail. Again on successful tests, all is ok but on failed test I get UTC. Is it possible to handle it somehow? Hope you got my point)))

Comment: ok, but I am going to post you an answer on a better solution.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, that would be cool of you ))) thank you Gerhard for your kind help)))

Comment: Maybe changing `cmd /C` to `call` solves your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you already had `UTC` which was set with your initial test and it was inherited.. anyway, I would rather do something like this.

I would use `delims=` instead of `tokens=*` Setting of variables is best done by closing them in double quotes starting at the beginning of the property, to the end of its value. i.e `set "PREVIOUS_TZ=%%f"` I amended the variable names to better suit my feel.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('tzutil /g') do set "oldtz=%%f"
tzutil /s "UTC"
cmd.exe /c npm run test:unit:base
tzutil /s "%oldtz%"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('tzutil /g') do if not "%oldtz%" == "%%a" (
    echo Old timezone of "%oldtz%" was not set successfully. It is still %%a
)
pause
```

This should set it perfectly fine each time, but in the event it does not, it will tell you about it.

Comment: Hi Gerhard, I am sorry but if I cancel test midway, timezone does not change back but remain UTC. That is, if I run test and midway click ctrl + c then UTC remain but would be great to return back the previous time zone. Please can you help((

Comment: yes because Ctrl+c will stop the batch sequence. The only way around it, which is not recommended is to start the test in a separate window. so instead try `start "" /wait npm run test:unit:base`

Comment: should I put start "" /wait npm run test:unit:base instead of cmd.exe /c npm run test:unit:base Right?

Comment: Pretty much yes

Comment: Please remember/note, from both [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60169565), and [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) by @aschipfl, that `npm` is really `npm.cmd`, not `npm.exe`!

Comment: @compo hence the comment "not recommended"

Comment: Sorry, @Gerhard, the comment was intended for all readers who may have visited here based upon the newly posted question regarding the CTRL-C issue, not specifically to yourself. _(as you know, I usually try to specifically name the person I'm addressing should that be my intention)_

Answer (score 1):

I would offer this methodology:

```bat
@Echo Off

Rem Enter your required interim timezone below here.
Set "Interim_TZ=UTC"

Rem The next four non remarked lines determine,
Rem  whether your current timezone requires changing to the interim one,
Rem  and defines a variable containing your current one, if it does.
Set "Initial_TZ="
For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    '""%__AppDir__%tzutil.exe" /G | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /VXC:"%Interim_TZ%""'
) Do Set "Initial_TZ=%%G"

Rem The below line will change the timezone, if it is not currently the interim one.
If Defined Initial_TZ "%__AppDir__%tzutil.exe" /S "%Interim_TZ%"

Rem Your commands using the interim timezone go below here.
Call "%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\npm.cmd" run test:unit:base

Rem If your initial timezone was different from the interim one,
Rem and you no longer need it assigned to the interim one,
Rem the next non remarked line changes it back again.
If Defined Initial_TZ "%__AppDir__%tzutil.exe" /S "%Initial_TZ%"
```

The idea is that it checks your current timezone, and if it is not already `UTC` it sets a variable containing that timezone. The timezone is then only changed and reverted if there was a need to. I have additionally used `Call` to invoke the `npm` command in the same window as your running script. *If I have guessed its path incorrectly, please change it as needed.*

Comment: thank you for your kind answer, yeah tried your solution and also works perfectly. just wanted to ask I have this npm script "test:unit:unix": "TZ=UTC npm run test:unit", is it possible to somehow change TZ back to previous after the completion of tests?

Comment: Unfortunately, @MII, I do not understand what you are now asking. The code above runs every command between the first and last `If Defined Initial_TZ` lines using the iterim timezone. I have modified my answer above to include the interim timezone as a variable, and add `Rem`arks to explain what is happening. If you try better to explain what you need to do, i.e what command(s) you now need to run, with what arguments, we may be able to assist you further.