# How to return previous timezone if we cancel the testing midway with ctrl+c

Tags: batch-file

I was creating batch script file for tests, I mean, I want to ensure that after the completion of tests the timezone returns back to previous as it was. Here is the script:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('tzutil /g') do set "oldtz=%%f"
tzutil /s "UTC"
cmd.exe /c npm run test:unit:base
tzutil /s "%oldtz%"
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('tzutil /g') do if not "%oldtz%" == "%%a" (
    echo Old timezone of "%oldtz%" was not set successfully. It is still %%a
)
pause
```

but this script does not return the previous timezone if I cancel the testing midway by clicking ctrl + c. Is it possible to ensure that even if we cancel tests the privious timezone returns back?

Comment: Duplicate question. I already commented there for you. [How is it possible to return back the changed timezone after the completion of tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60167366/how-is-it-possible-to-return-back-the-changed-timezone-after-the-completion-of-t)

Comment: If you forcibly stop the script from running,( i.e. before it gets to the line containing the command to change the timezone back), then obviously it will not be able to run that command! Is there a particular reason why it has take you until now to tell us that the issue is you're forcibly closing the NPM script, before it is being completed?